# explanation for cross entropy for logistic regression

Tags: machine-learning, entropy, logistic-regression

as far as I know, cross entropy of two distributions is:
$$
C(p,q) = -\sum_{s \in classes}p(s)\log(q(s))
$$
however, the loss function for logistic regression (called "crossentropy loss") it's defined as:
$$
J(\theta) = -\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^my^{(i)} \:\cdot\: log(h_\theta(x^{(i)}))+(1-y^{(i)})\:\cdot\:log(1-h_\theta(x^{(i)}))
$$
as far as I know, $y$ and $(1-y)$ are just term to handle the error in case of miss-classification in both ways, and this makes me really miss the connection with the crossentropy definition, ergo, I don't see why it's called like that, even though i don't see any connection between the 2 formulas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the crossentropy loss, $y$ is either $0$ or $1$.
It can be seen as the **exact** probability of an example belongs to class 1 or class 2
So $\mathbb{P}(w=1|\mathbf{x}) = y$ and
$\mathbb{P}(w=2|\mathbf{x}) = 1-y$

Identically $h_\theta(\mathbf{x})$ is the **predicted** probability of an example belonging to class 1 or class 2.
So $\mathbb{P}(w=1) = h_\theta(\mathbf{x})$ and
$\mathbb{P}(w=2) = 1-h_\theta(\mathbf{x})$.

This should make clear the connection with the definition of cross-entropy.
Note that your second definition is a kind of average cross-entropy (you are summung over examples, but your indices seem wrong)

Comment: sure, I was missing the indices.... but I don't get which are 2 distributions on which we are calculating the crossentropy ($p,q$)

Comment: p,q are probability mass functions that give the probability that a discrete random variable (the class) is exactly 1 or 2 (these numbers are arbitrary)

Comment: So our $\frac{1}{m}\sum...$ is just a "estimation" of the $p(t)$ of the first formula (ergo, the probability is the proportion of elements)?